# 2つのリストを比較して値を入れ替える方法

Tags: python, python3

2つリストがあり，一つはデータIDを表す数字が入った長さ2708のリスト`A`があります．
また，もう一つはデータを表す長さ21664のリスト`B`です．`B`に格納されているデータの値の幅は0~2707です．
この2つのリスト`A,B`を比較して，`B`の値を`A`のリスト番号に一致するデータIDと入れ替えるというコードを作りたいです．
以下が例です．

```
A = [626531, 1131180, 1130454, 1131184, 1128974, 1128975, 1128977, 1128978, 117328, 24043]
B = [2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 9, 0]
```

期待する出力

> lst = [1130454, 1131184, 1128977, 1131180, 1131180, 24043, 626531]

いろいろ試しましたが，思うようにいきません．　解決方法が分かる方いましたら回答お願いします．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst=[A[x] for x in B]
```

でいいんじゃないですかね

Answer (score 2):

参考までに、`numpy.array` の場合、list や tuple で indexing が可能です。

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst = np.array(A)[B].tolist()
>>> lst
[1130454, 1131184, 1128977, 1131180, 1131180, 24043, 626531]
```